# I can't build I got error Could not load assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have to problem with Xamarin android not build successfully and I got error message really strange

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Exception while loading assemblies:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: C ould not load assembly
>   'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono
>   for Android profile? File name: 'netstandard.dll'    at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly,
>   Boolean topLevel)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   resolver) Art.Cleopatra.Android

I don't know what is the problem exactly

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before and fixed it by uninstalling Xamarin packages from NuGet and then reinstalling them. Or creating a new project and adding your files to that project.

I am unsure of the root cause but this worked for me.